# How can I parse JSON from a rest API in swift

Tags: swift, closures

I'm modifying code from 'Hacking with swift' Project 7 to take a JSON file using an API and placing it in a table view

I'm at a bit of loss of what to do next, tried moving around the call to the parse function and using the commented out code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let username = "UserName"
    let password = "Password"
    let loginData = String(format: "%@:%@", username,
                           password).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let base64LoginData = loginData.base64EncodedString()

    let url = URL(string: "......")!
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginData)", forHTTPHeaderField:
        "Authorization")


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data,
        response,
        error in

        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            parse(json: data)
            print("status code = \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

//       if let url = URL(string: urlstring){
//          if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url){
//                parse(json: data)
//                return
//           }
//        }
//        showError()
//}

func parse(json: Data) {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    if let jsonPetitions = try? decoder.decode(Petitions.self, from:
        json) {
        petitions = jsonPetitions.results
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

I receive a status code of '200' so I know the API call works fine.

The issue seems to be with calling the parse function I get the 
following error "Call to method 'parse' in closure requires explicit 
'self.' to make capture semantics explicit"

Comment: `self.parse(json: data)`

Comment: Cheers, this removes the error but the cells don’t populate with any data

Comment: Do you set the delegate and data source ?

Comment: Don't `try?`. **Catch** the error and `print` it. Decoding errors are very descriptive.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

1- The error means to add `self` here

```
 self.parse(json: data)
```

2- You should reload the table in main thread as callback of `URLSession.shared.dataTask` runs in a background thread to avoid un-expected results/crashes

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```